# Create responsive sub navigation items with CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive-design

I have to create a navigation based on a mockup design created in Photoshop. The mockup currently looks like this:

[image]

I already managed to create the main navigation points and now I am facing some problems with the sub navigation. It should be responsive, that means the maximal number of items in the sub navigation should be 4, the minimal number of items should be 2. Is it possible with CSS to position the single elements next to each other automatically?

This is what I already have:

```
<div id="topnavigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">PORTRAIT</a></li>
      <li id="restaurants"><a href="#" class="active">RESTAURANTS</a></li>
      <li id="restaurants_sub">
          <div class="wrapper_boxes"><div id="restaurants_sub_content" class="sub_boxes"><span>lövenstube</span><br>Master deanse bes-<br>poke brooklyn, wiliams-<br>burg minim id wayfa</div></div>
          <div class="wrapper_boxes"><div id="restaurants_sub_content" class="sub_boxes"><span>lövenstube</span><br>Master deanse bes-<br>poke brooklyn, wiliams-<br>burg minim id wayfa</div></div>      
          <div class="wrapper_boxes"><div id="restaurants_sub_content" class="sub_boxes"><span>lövenstube</span><br>Master deanse bes-<br>poke brooklyn, wiliams-<br>burg minim id wayfa</div></div>
          <div class="wrapper_boxes"><div id="restaurants_sub_content" class="sub_boxes"><span>lövenstube</span><br>Master deanse bes-<br>poke brooklyn, wiliams-<br>burg minim id wayfa</div></div>
          <div class="wrapper_boxes"><div id="restaurants_sub_content" class="sub_boxes"><span>lövenstube</span><br>Master deanse bes-<br>poke brooklyn, wiliams-<br>burg minim id wayfa</div></div>
          <div class="wrapper_boxes"><div id="restaurants_sub_content" class="sub_boxes"><span>lövenstube</span><br>Master deanse bes-<br>poke brooklyn, wiliams-<br>burg minim id wayfa</div></div>
          <div class="wrapper_boxes"><div id="restaurants_sub_content" class="sub_boxes"><span>lövenstube</span><br>Master deanse bes-<br>poke brooklyn, wiliams-<br>burg minim id wayfa</div></div>
          <div class="wrapper_boxes"><div id="restaurants_sub_content" class="sub_boxes"><span>lövenstube</span><br>Master deanse bes-<br>poke brooklyn, wiliams-<br>burg minim id wayfa</div></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">HOTEL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FESTE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SEMINARE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">VERANSTALTUNGEN</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

All hints are appreciated! Thx.

Comment: "Is it possible with CSS to position the single elements next to each other automatically?"  Which elements are you referring to?

Comment: Lövenstube, Bistro, Verdana, etc. Those are the sigle sub navigation elements.

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle with some CSS with what you've already tried?

Comment: Try adding the class `.sub_boxes span { display: inline-block; float: left; }`  Also, if you remove the `<br>` tags, since they are inline elements, they should automatically appear next to eachother.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/doonot/Q5agr/

Comment: Your fiddle will only allow 3 elements across as the width of the container is 600px and the elements are 200px each.  That and the padding that adds to their width.

Comment: Here is an update of your jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Q5agr/1/.  Though you will have to try the updated CSS elsewhere as the dimensions are too large for the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float `.sub_boxes` left and set a min-width and max-width on `#restaurants_sub` that will only hold 2-4 `.sub_boxes`.

http://jsfiddle.net/xBPjP/

Something like this in your CSS

```css
#topnavigation li {
     clear: left;
}
#restaurants_sub {
     max-width: 400px;
}
.sub_boxes {
     width: 100px;
     float: left;
}
```